# BULK INSERT problem in MySQL

Tags: mysql, csv, bulkinsert

I get an error with the following SQL command for bulk insert.

```
    BULK INSERT libra.faculty
    FROM 'd\:faculty.csv'
    WITH
    (
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
    );
```

Here's the error message:

```
    ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
    corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BULK
    INSERT libra.faculty
    FROM 'd:\faculty.csv'
    WITH
    (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    RO' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) instead of `BULK INSERT`

Comment: Worked like a charm.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

LOAD DATA INFILE 'd:faculty.csv'  INTO TABLE libra.faculty FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'