# Large records table insertion issue Mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join, large-data

I am a developer and I am facing an issue while managing table which has large amount of records.

I am executing a cron job to fill up data in primary table (Table A) which has 5-6 columns and approx 4,00,000 to 5,00,000 rows and then creating another table and data in this table would continue to increase over the time.

TABLE A contains the raw data and my output table is TABLE B

My cron script truncates data in Table B then inserts data using select query

```
TRUNCATE TABLE_B; 

INSERT INTO TABLE_B (field1, field2) 
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.field2), t2.field2 
FROM TABLE_A AS t1 
INNER JOIN TABLE_A t2 ON t2.field1=t1.field1 
WHERE t1.field2 <> t2.field2 
GROUP BY t1.field2, t2.field2 
ORDER BY COUNT(t1.field2) DESC;
```

Above select query produces approx 1,50,000 to 2,00,000 rows

Now it takes too much time to populate TABLE B and meanwhile If my application tries to access TABLE B then select query fails

Explaining query results following:

```
'1','PRIMARY','T1','ALL','field1_index',NULL,NULL,NULL,'431743','Using temporary;Using filesort' 
'1','PRIMARY','T2','ref','field1_index','field1_index','767','DBNAME.T1.field1','1','Using where'
```

Can someone please help me in improving this process, or guide me alternatives for above process?

Thanks

Suketu

Comment: This type of question has been asked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838828/bulk-insert-problem-in-mysql

Comment: For the EXPLAIN syntax to be useful please include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLES` for both of the tables.

Comment: `code` CREATE TABLE `TABLE_A` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `field1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `field2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `count_field3` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_4` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `field2_index` (`field2`),
  KEY `field1_index` (`field1`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=435692 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 `code`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do the whole process in a stored proc.

Do not truncate such a large table. Follow the following steps:

1. Copy the TableB structure to TableB_Copy.
2. DROP TABLEB.
3. Rename TableB_Copy to TableB
4. Disable indexes on TableB
5. Insert the data from TableA into TableB
6. Create the indexes on TableB.

Comment: wouldn't it be cleaner to make a copy, populate it and then roll it in with `RENAME TABLE tableB TO tableB_old, tableB_new TO tableB`?

Answer (score 0):

According to my view the solution would be like this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(t1.field2), t2.field2 
    FROM 
        TABLE_A AS t1
    INNER JOIN 
        TABLE_A t2 ON 
        t2.field1=t1.field1 
    WHERE
        t1.field2 <> t2.field2 
    GROUP BY
        t1.field2, t2.field2 
    ORDER BY
       COUNT(t1.field2)
    DESC INTO OUTPUT "PATH-TO-FILE";
```

For instance file as "C:\TEMP\DATA1.SQL". What will happen with this query a simple new file is created with TAB delimiter to insert into any table.
Now how to import the data to table.

```
LOAD DATA
    "PATH-TO-FILE"
INTO TABLE
     table_name
```

With this query the data will be inserted and on the other hand you will be able to use the table in which you are inserting the data.