# Doing a bulk SQL insert in django

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

Suppose I have a CSV file with 1M email addresses. I need to iterate through the file and add each entry, for example:

```
with open(file) as csv:
    for item in csv:
        Email.objects.create(email=item)
```

This seems like it would be very slow going through the django ORM like this to create 1M objects and insert them into the db. Is there a better way than this, or should I go away from django for this task and do it directly with the db?

Comment: You shouldn't use `csv` as a variable since its the name of a built-in module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides `bulk_create`, you could put all inserts into one transaction as long as your DB backend supports it:

```
from django.db.transaction import commit_on_success
#  with commit_on_success(), open(file) as csv: # in Python2.7
with commit_on_success():
    for item in csv:
        Email.objects.create(email=item)
```

Also note that `bulk_create` treats items w/ same values to be same, thus

```
Email.objects.bulk_create([Email(email=item), Email(email=item)])
```

actually creates one row instead of two

Because of more SQLs turnaround, the transaction solution is still slower than the `bulk_create` one, but you don't have to create all one million `Email()` instances in memory (generator seems not work here)

Furthermore, you could [do it in SQL-level directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838828/bulk-insert-problem-in-mysql)

Answer (score 4):

You can also try using new [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Answer (score 1):

This is something you should drop to DB-API to accomplish, since you bypass creating all the model objects.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, I don't see very big problem with speed if it's only one-time insert (1M records won't take you hours). If you'll be using django api to access those objects in the future, then probably you should avoid resorting to SQL level insert, and do it through django's methods, like suggested by livar (if using django 1.4)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into the [Django DSE](http://djangopackages.com/packages/p/dse/) package, which is apparently an efficient bulk insert/update library.